# How to find the second highest number in an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods

Working on a program where we need separate methods to find the highest and second highest numbers. My code finds the highest number just fine but I can't figure out how to find the second highest number.

```
public static int highestNumber(int []array1) {

  int max = -999999;

     for (int i = 1; i < array1.length; i++) {
         if (array1[i] > max) {
            max = array1[i];
            }
           } 
     return max;
```

}

```
  public static int secondHighest(int []array1) {

      int highest= highestNumber(array1);
    int secondHighest = array1[0];

           for (int i=1; i<array1.length; i++){
              if(array1[i]> highest && array1[i] secondHighest);
                    secondHighest=array1[i];
                }
  return secondHighest;
 }
```

Comment: You have to use two "separate" methods!?

Comment: Is there a typo in your code?  Should it be `if(array1[i]> highest && array1[i] < secondHighest);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not prefered using -9999999, use Integer.MIN_VALUE or use first index of array instead, 
but when use first index, make sure the length of array must greater or equals 1

```
public static int secondHighest(int[] array1)
{
    int highest = highestNumber(array1);

    int max = array[0];
    for( int i = 1; i < array1.Length; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] > max && array[i] < highest){
            max = array[i];
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int secondHighest(int[] array1)
{
    int highest = highestNumber(array1);
    int max = -9999999;

    for( int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
    {
        if(array[i] > max && array[i] < highest) max = array[i];
    }

    return max;
}
```